# Verifying user via email

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know good sample code, using ASP.net security, that sets up a sample Visual Studio 2010 application, along with a log in page, and the logic/code to verify users who sign up via email? I feel like this must have been written thousands of times.

Comment: +1 "this must have been written thousands of times"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you the URL that I started with. You can go form that to a different approach if you like but that is well explained and you can understand what you need to do:

http://forums.asp.net/post/1860807.aspx

please notice that the example there is old and you will need some ADO.NET understanding but the idea is the same